# Recode Datatable Column with Linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a table in my SQL server that looks like:

```
|Calendarweek| Hours|
|1           |4     |
|2           |5     |
```

...

I get this table into a dataset and query it with linq. Now the problem is, that in our business logic the first week is the first week in april. I have a method that finds the first week in April for me for the given year. What I need to do now is to recode the Calendarweeks. So for this year the `Calendarweek 14 = 1, Calendarweek 15 = 2` and so forth.

I went through all the Linq Extensions but couldnt find a way to recode. Does anyone can help me with this?

For a start I can simplify my query to:

```
dim query = from row in datatable1.AsEnumerable
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recode", do you want to update the data?  or do you want to transform it. e.g. `query.Select(x => new { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that the first week is 14, why can't you simply add 14 to the `Calendarweek`-value in the table?

```
Dim query = From row In datatable1.AsEnumerable
            Let Calendarweek = row.Field(Of Int32)("Calendarweek")
            Let Hours = row.Field(Of Int32)("Hours")
            Select x = New With {
                .Calendarweek = Calendarweek,
                .Hours = Hours,
                .RealWeek = Calendarweek + 14
            }
```

Replace 14 with a method that gives to the correct value(it's not that clear).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a anonymous type that calls a method.

```
dim query = from row in datatable1.AsEnumerable
            select new
            {
                Hours = row.Hours,
                Calendarweek = MyConversionMethod(row.Calendarweek)
            };
```

You'll need to change `row.Hours` to be whatever the datatable uses, I think named columns? So maybe `row["Hours"]`.